# (Python bot) Как отмечать людей в беседе через бота?

Tags: python, бот

у меня интересный вопрос. У меня есть бот на vk(написан на Python). Как сделать так чтобы он через цикл мог отмечать определенным символом участников беседы? Например как можно сделать это в вк @id и человек отмечен и ему пришло уведомление. Только мне нужно чтобы бот написал символы $$$$$$$$$ и каждый символ $ отмечал человека в беседе. В ручную сделать никак, так как придется все время открывать код и добавлять нового человека.

Вот мой код

```
import vk_api
import random
import time

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="021cad5014bf87033caafb6f6b3583a01018dbf391a48f05ea92a5b37e710c897d44278e13f66af7a1381")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["POST"])
def main():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    if data["type"] == "confirmation":
        return "0f05cbd9"
    elif data["type"] == "message_new":
        object = data["object"]
        id = object["peer_id"]
        body = object["text"]
        if ("крут" in body.lower() or "cool" in body.lower()) and "полностью согласен! реально круто " != body.lower():
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "О да, это точно круто! ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "привет" in body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Привет! Как жизнь?", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "как дела" in body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "У меня все круто! Надеюсь у тебя также.", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "начать" == body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Ну шо, погнали. Команды гадай сам или спроси у Санчая.", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif body.lower() == "бот, ссылку":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Бро, подпишись vk.com/sanchbot", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "ватафак" in body.lower():
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Ват ю сей, мен! Ватафак!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif body.lower() == "тиха":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Тсссссссссссс!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "флекс" in body.lower():
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "О да! ФЛЕКСИМ! ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "яратам" in body.lower():
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Мин сине яратам! ❤", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "татмак" in body.lower():
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Мммм.. Татмаки, Родя сказал они вкусные", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "добрый вечер" in body.lower():
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Добрейший вечерочек ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "доброе утро" in body.lower():
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Добрейшее утречко, господа ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "добрый день" in body.lower():
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Добрый день, сэр! ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif body.lower() == "бот, поздоровайся":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Экии привет", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "что мне сегодня приготовить" in body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Можешь приготовить мое сердечко ❤", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "нарут" in body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Наруто - это круто!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "надевай очки" in body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "good morning" in body.lower() or "гуд монинг" in body.lower() or "гуд морнинг" in body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Доброе утро! Хорошего вам дня ❤", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "доброй ночи" in body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Сладких снов ❤", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "всем хорошего дня" in body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "И тебе хорошего дня!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "ех" in body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Еех!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif "я ною" in body.lower():
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Вот именно! Че ты ноешь?!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
    return "ok"
```

Comment: Для упоминания отправьте сообщение вида `[id123456789|текст]`, где `123456789` - это `id` пользователя, а `текст` - текст упоминания. Такие конструкции можно последовательно комбинировать, чтобы добиться необходимого результата. Для того, чтобы получить `id` всех пользователей беседы, можно отправить запрос к `vk API`. И ещё, пожалуйста, перепишите Ваш код, используя словарь для хранения записей `{'вопрос': 'ответ'}`. А `random_id` можно получить одноимённой функцией из модуля `vk_api.tools`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для упоминания необходимо отправить сообщение вида `[id123456789|текст]`, где `123456789` - это `id` пользователя, а `текст` - текст упоминания.

Для того, чтобы получить `id` всех пользователей беседы, можно отправить запрос к `vk API`, а именно к методу `getConversationMembers`. Имейте в виду, что боту необходимы права администратора беседы.

Также я позволил себе исключать участников с отрицательным `id`. Такой `id` у сообществ, то есть у нашего и других ботов.

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import settings


vkBotSession = VkApi(token=settings.accessToken)
vk = vkBotSession.get_api()


def main():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id=2000000000,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = ''
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=2000000000,
        message=message,
        random_id=get_random_id()
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В `settings.py` у меня находятся токены. Замените на свои. Также следует заменить все `peer_id` в коде на `peer_id` конкретно Вашей беседы.

Ну и не знаю уж почему, ВК не желает форматировать упоминание со знаком `$` (хотя уведомление приходит), поэтому я заменил знак на `#`.

**UPD:**

Для того чтобы получить `peer_id` я пользуюсь данным скриптом:

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

import settings  # В этом файле у меня токены


vkSession = VkApi(token=settings.accessToken)
longPoll = VkBotLongPoll(vkSession, settings.groupId)
vk = vkSession.get_api()


def main() -> None:
    for event in longPoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            print(event.obj['peer_id'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Всё что требуется - отправить сообщение в беседу с ботом.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Как узнать peer_id беседы? Я просто гуглил ничего не нашел

Comment: @WazzzUp Я отсылаю сообщение боту из нужной беседы и смотрю на `event`, который прислал мне ВК. В нём будет поле `peer_id`, которое нам и нужно. Но ещё есть специальный метод [`getConversations`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversations)

Comment: Нельзя ли сделать так чтобы бот реагировал только на мою команду через if (user_id == "my id"): и обойтись без peer_id. То есть чтобы бот реагировал только на сообщение присланное в опредленной беседе.

Comment: @WazzzUp `peer_id` - это универсальный идентификатор. У каждой беседы он уникален (в личных сообщениях тоже), поэтому я его и использовал. Когда Вам приходит сообщение, оно содержит в себе `peer_id` беседы, из которой пришло (если у бота есть права администратора). Вы можете проверить его, чтобы точно идентифицировать беседу. То есть использовать `if peer_id == 'my_peer_id'` можно. Зачем от него отказываться, я не понимаю. К тому же `peer_id` нужен для того, чтобы получить всех участников беседы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я никак не могу найти peer_id беседы, делал запросы через getConversations выдает код, там виден id отправителя и id сообщения. Можете подсказать какое ключевое слово содержит id беседы?

Comment: @WazzzUp Я обновил ответ, добавив небольшой скрипт, попробуйте.

Comment: Все работает круто! Спасибо!

Comment: @WazzzUp Если ответ Вам помог, то Вы можете отметить его как верный.