# (Python bot) Как отмечать людей в беседе через бота?#2

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Взял код из коммента тут [(Python bot) Как отмечать людей в беседе через бота?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011387/python-bot-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0) 
Но у меня вызывается бот только при запуске , по команде не работает.

```py
while True:
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.object.peer_id != event.object.from_id:
                    if event.object.text.lower() == "призыв":
                        def main():
                            members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
                                peer_id=2000000001,
                            )['items']

                            members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

                            message = ''
                            for member_id in members_ids:
                                message += f'[id{member_id}|Люди]'

                            vk.messages.send(
                                peer_id=2000000001,
                                message=message,
                                random_id=get_random_id()
                            )


                        if __name__ == '__main__':
                            main()
         except Exception as E:
        print(Exception)
```

Ошибка:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/skise/PycharmProjects/отправлялка/отправка.py", line 14, in

for event in longpoll.listen():

NameError: name 'longpoll' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Вероятная причина ошибки - `peer_id`, указанный напрямую в коде:

```py
...
peer_id=2000000001,
...
```

Если у бота ваш диалог имеет ID, отличный от 1, бот работает некорректно. Советую брать `peer_id` напрямую из `event`:

```py
...
peer_id = event.object.peer_id
...
```

*Ответ обновлён:*

> NameError: name 'longpoll' is not defined

Вы не объявили переменную `longpoll`
Если вы используете [этот](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/longpoll.py) модуль API, объявление выглядит следующим образом:

```py
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен группы')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'ID группы')
```

([Пример bot longpoll этого модуля](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/bot_longpoll.py))

Если же вы используете другой модуль, вам необходимо найти документацию к нему. В любом случае, попробуйте именно этот код. Возможно, даже при использовании другого модуля, объявление сессии и слушателя выглядит сходным образом.

Comment: Теперь он читает , но не пишет. В Run вылезает <class 'Exception'> .

Comment: @СергейАндреев Попробуйте убрать блок `try-except` и посмотреть в консоли, какое именно исключение вызывается. Добавьте это в свой вопрос

Comment: Добавил ниже кода.

Comment: @СергейАндреев обновил ответ, проверяйте

Comment: Попробовал так, но теперь другая ошибка :                                              longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, 19149***4)
NameError: name 'vk' is not defined  .                                                                                               Попробовал импортировать vk  и заменить( и не заменять, всё ровно ошибка)  vk_session  и опять ошибка :                                                                                                               
members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
AttributeError: 'VkApi' object has no attribute 'messages'.

Comment: @СергейАндреев вам нужно найти документацию именно по тому модулю, который вы используете